# Kind of applications that can be based on dotnet framework alone

Tags: .net

i am intend to do a web application and host it. Since i have some knowledge 
in Asp.Netand C#, i decided to develop using DotNet.

I am not sure about the licencing from microsoft for dotnet.

My question is :

Is it possible to use only **dotnet framework** which is free and use MySql as
backend to develop a webapplication and host it without buying licence ?
If so what editor can i use to develop the application ?

Pls suggest me some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio offers several express editions that are completely free. There is even a free express edition of SQL Server, but you could certainly use MySql too. http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

Comment: @Josh Einstein. yeah for development purpose i can use it . What about Hosing the web application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any runtime licenses at all unless you use SQL Server.

For development, you can use the free Visual Web Developer Express Edition.

Comment: So i can develop my web application using visual studio express edition with MySql as backend and host it legally without paying for any license IS IT ?

Comment: Even if the web application is for a commercial purpose ?

Comment: Correct.  You will need a license for Windows Server, though.  If you're using shared hosting, you don't need to worry about licensing at all.

Comment: @SLAKS, sorry could not get your point. Say if i completed my development and want to host it. i dont need to own any of the servers to servers to have windows server licence. I can still host in any of the data centers right ?

Comment: @Anuya: Assuming that the data centers are legal, yes.  ASP.Net and IIS do not have any licensing requirements.  (but Windows does)

Comment: SLaks, you don't need a license for SQL Server Express edition.